# Required request part 'file' is not present from axios request using multer file input

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, express, axios, multer

I am working on a node app using express calling a spring-boot backend with an http post request using axios. The request in the node app is a multipart form-data request, which is handled by multer in the node contoller layer. consequently I have a buffer which I am using to create a form-data object to pass in my axios request to my spring-boot backend.

When calling the back end however I am getting

Required request part 'file' is not present

I have also tried to read the request in the spring-boot layer as a straight up httpservletrequest and that shows the part is present but then interpreting the Part to a MultipartFile is proving a challege

Multer options and method

```
const multerOptions = {
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
};
exports.upload = multer(multerOptions).single('file');
```

method call using req.file

```
uploadResult = await uploadTrack(req.file);
```

axios request to backend

```
const uploadTrack = async (uploadTrack) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let file = streamifier.createReadStream(uploadTrack.buffer);
    formData.append('file', file);

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/trackUpload', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`}});
}
```

spring boot controller

```java
@PostMapping("/trackUpload")
    public ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                           RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        String outcome = "successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        try {
            storageService.store(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            outcome = "failed to save " + file.getOriginalFilename();

            return new ResponseEntity(outcome, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(outcome, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

the full error (actually a WARN) message doesn't have a stack and is thrown by spring boot before entering the controller

WARN 3923 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

Answer (score 1):

So I have a hack of a solution, this is not the accepted answer cause I hate it.

I stuck the file name in the request, and extracted the parts from the servlet request in a known order and wrote them as an inputStream to a file

```java
@PostMapping("/trackSave")
    public ResponseEntity handleFileSave(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
            ArrayList<Part> partsList = new ArrayList<Part>(parts);
            String filename = partsList.get(1).getName();
            File file = new File(FILE_TO + filename);
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(partsList.get(0).getInputStream(), file);
            return new ResponseEntity("Success, " + filename + " saved", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity("unable to save file", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Yuck, please give me a better solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you have to do is change your formData to the following

```
formData.append('file', file, "filename");
```

Notice the addition of giving it a file name?  Try that out I believe that will work with the original code.